# Using a function (R) to improve code for Fisher's exact

Tags: r

I'm trying to make my code more elegant. I want to produce a Fisher's exact test across 2 groups for 3 different criteria (essentially 3 tests). I have a solution, but it's cumbersome. I wonder if there is a way to write a function to achieve the same...

My solution:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"),
+                  criteria = c("fever", "fever", "headache", "headache", "chills", "chills"),
+                  absent = c(35, 31, 78, 163, 53, 33),
+                  present = c(62, 154, 19, 22, 44, 152))
```

Now to do the Fisher's test to compare groups A & B on fever, then headache, then chills.

```
#Compare A & B on fever
fever <- df %>% filter(criteria=="fever") %>% select(-criteria)
fever <- column_to_rownames(fever, var = "group")
fisher.test(fever)

#Compare A & B on headache
headache <- df %>% filter(criteria=="headache") %>% select(-criteria)
headache <- column_to_rownames(headache, var = "group")
fisher.test(headache)

#Compare A & B on chills
chills <- df %>% filter(criteria=="chills") %>% select(-criteria)
chills <- column_to_rownames(chills, var = "group")
fisher.test(chills)
```

I want to be able to print do Fisher's tests on all different criteria (bearing in mind in reality I have more than 3) without having to type things out separately. I guess this is possible with a function, but I don't really know where to start...

Would be grateful for assistance... pls go easy I'm a clinician not an informatician!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `group_by` `criteria` and apply `fisher.test` to each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  select(-group) %>%
  group_by(criteria) %>%
  summarise(fisher_test = list(fisher.test(cur_data()))) -> result

result$fisher_test

#[[1]]

#   Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

#data:  cur_data()
#p-value = 0.0000000004
#alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
#95 percent confidence interval:
# 3.09 9.97
#sample estimates:
#odds ratio 
#      5.51 


#[[2]]

#   Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

#data:  cur_data()
#p-value = 0.0004
#alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
#95 percent confidence interval:
# 1.53 5.14
#sample estimates:
#odds ratio 
#      2.79 


#[[3]]

#   Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

#data:  cur_data()
#p-value = 0.1
#alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
#95 percent confidence interval:
# 0.269 1.154
#sample estimates:
#odds ratio 
#     0.555
```

---

In base R you could use `by` or `split` + `lapply` :

```
by(df[3:4], df$criteria, fisher.test)
#OR
lapply(split(df[3:4], df$criteria), fisher.test)
```

Comment: Thank you! Base R solution best as it gives the criteria with the result.